# how to manage mongorito connection in node.js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use mongorito as mongodb library in nodejs application. But I am wondering should I open connection and close connection per request, or I can use connection pool if it is existed.

Cheers,
Ron

Comment: Mongorito is based on [`monk`](https://github.com/Automattic/monk), which is based on [`mongoskin`](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin), which is based on [`node-mongodb-native`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/), which has its own connection pool (see [the `poolSize` option](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Server.html)). Just open a connection once, and reuse it for your queries.